# Computer does not register MIDI signal C4 and D4, all the other keys are working fine, could the problem be the cable or the keyboard

Tags: midi, usb

Today for the first time I tried to connect my keyboard (Hohner PSK50) to the computer. I made the connection by using this [cable](https://www.onlinekabe4lshop.nl/usb-midi-input-en-midi-output-kabel-1-8-meter). (A simple MIDI to USB). Drivers were recognized and when I tried to use the Keyboard in FL-studio I noticed that all the inputs came through correctly except the C4 and D4. Those keys often didn't register and when they sometimes did, it registered as an E2.

This is gamebreaking. So I want to fix this. My question is:

Could this possibly be the cable (MIDI to USB)? Or can the only problem causer be the keyboard itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the keyboard itself plays correctly on the analog channel, it's likely to be the USB adapter.  I took a look at your link (after correcting it in the obvious way since it has a spurious `4` in it) and those Chinese USB/Midi adapters with the violin clef on them are garbage.  While they typically work using just single notes, they have problems with chording and they mangle Sysreq data, so even if note play worked reasonably (which in your case it doesn't), you'd get into problem trying to dump and restore settings.

Try getting a USB/Midi adapter produced by a reputable company (since Midi is a low bitspeed protocol, it doesn't need to be USB2.0 HiSpeed).  They've been around for a long time, so the preowned market has pretty good prices as well.

Comment: Thank you for the response, since I just bought this cable I will return it and get a high-quality cable. I was thinking about this one: https://www.tie-products.com/en/product/midi-1i1o/